# Can macros be used to simulate C++ templated functions?

Tags: c, macros

I have a C program in which I need to create a whole family of functions which have the same signatures and bodies, and differ only in their types. What I would like to do is define a macro which generates all of those functions for me, as otherwise I will spend a long time copying and modifying the original functions. As an example, one of the functions I need to generate looks like this:

`int copy_key__sint_(void *key, void **args, int argc, void **out {

    if ((*out = malloc(sizeof(int))) {

        return 1;

    }`

```
**((_int_ **) out) = *((_int_ *) key);  
return 0;
```

}

The idea is that I could call a macro, GENERATE_FUNCTIONS("int", "sint") or something like this, and have it generate this function. The italicized parts are what need to be plugged in.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the example function that you are giving very well, but using macros for the task is relatively easy. Just you wouldn't give strings to the macro as arguments but *tokens*:

```
#define DECLARE_MY_COPY_FUNCTION(TYPE, SUFFIX)              \
int copy_function_ ## SUFFIX(unsigned count, TYPE* arg)

#define DEFINE_MY_COPY_FUNCTION(TYPE, SUFFIX)               \
int copy_function_ ## SUFFIX(unsigned count, TYPE* arg) {   \
 /* do something with TYPE */                               \
 return whatever;                                           \
}
```

You may then use this to declare the functions in a header file

```
DECLARE_MY_COPY_FUNCTION(unsigned, toto);
DECLARE_MY_COPY_FUNCTION(double, hui);
```

and define them in a .c file:

```
DEFINE_MY_COPY_FUNCTION(unsigned, toto);
DEFINE_MY_COPY_FUNCTION(double, hui);
```

In this version as stated here you might get warnings on superfluous `;'. But you can get rid of them by adding dummy declarations in the macros like this

```
#define DEFINE_MY_COPY_FUNCTION(TYPE, SUFFIX)               \
int copy_function_ ## SUFFIX(unsigned count, TYPE* arg) {   \
 /* do something with TYPE */                               \
 return whatever;                                           \
}                                                           \
enum { dummy_enum_for_copy_function_ ## SUFFIX }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this (I just tested the compilation, but not the result in an executed program):

```
 #include "memory.h"

   #define COPY_KEY(type, name)                                 \
   type name(void *key, void **args, int argc, void **out) { \
      if (*out = malloc(sizeof(type))) {                     \
         return 1;                                           \
      }                                                      \
   **((type **) out) = *((type *) key);                      \
   return 0;                                                 \
   }                                                         \

COPY_KEY(int, copy_key_sint)
```

For more on the subject of generic programming in C, read [this blog wich contains a few examples](http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/generic-programming-in-c/) and also [this book which contains interesting solutions to the problem for basic data structures and algorithm.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201498413)

Answer (score 1):

That should work. To create `copy_key_sint`, use `copy_key_ ## sint`.

If you can't get this to work with CPP, then write a small C program which generates a C source file.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a macro which just takes `sizeof(*key)` and calls a single function that uses `memcpy` be a lot cleaner (less preprocessor abuse and code bloat) than making a new function for each type just so it can do a native assignment rather than `memcpy`?

My view is that the whole problem is your attempt to apply C++ thinking to C. C has `memcpy` for a very good reason.

Comment: @R.: I don't think this is answer to the question of the OP. I understand that code that he is giving as just one type of example of what kind of *declarations* he wants to achieve.

Comment: I think my answer applies to a large category of situations for which one might want "C++ templates for C". Often if you realize you can treat the data as an abstract byte array, or partly as such with a callback function for processing it (as in `qsort`, etc.), you're able to write much simpler and more efficient C code.

Comment: Does memcpy have a Windows implementation?